# Biztalk Recieve Location with new WCF-SAP adapter disables when connector type changes to Nco(Sap .net connector 3.0)

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am using the new WCF-SAP adapter with BizTalk 2013.This adapter gives the option to use the classic RFCSdk or the SAP .net connector. My SAP Receive location works fine with the classic RFCSdk connector type but when I change it to NCo my receive location doesn't enable. I receive the following error in the Application log  when I try to enable it after restarting the Host instance

```
The Messaging Engine failed to add a receive location "WcfReceiveLocation_SAPBinding_IdocDEBMAS05V3R740_Custom" with URL "**sap://CLIENT=300;LANG=EN;@a/sv-sapecc-dv2/00?GWHOST=sv-sapecc-dv2&GWSERV=sapgw00&ListenerDest=BIZTALKDEV&ListenerGwServ=sapgw00&ListenerGwHost=sv-sapecc-dv2&ListenerProgramId=BIZTALKDEV&RfcSdkTrace=True&AbapDebug=False**" to the adapter "WCF-Custom". Reason: "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.NCo.RfcServerConnection.GetParameters(String serverName)
   at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcServerManager.GetServer(String serverName, Type[] rfcFunctionHandlers, RfcRepository repository)
   at Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.NCo.RfcServerConnection.Open(RfcClientConnection conn)
   at Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SAPInboundContract.InitializeRfcServerConnectionNCo(String connectionArguments)
   at Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SAPInboundContract.StartListener(String[] listenerActions, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.Channels.AdapterChannelListener`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfReceiveEndpoint.Enable()
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfReceiveEndpoint..ctor(BizTalkEndpointContext endpointContext, IBTTransportProxy transportProxy, ControlledTermination control)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfReceiver`2.AddReceiveEndpoint(String url, IPropertyBag adapterConfig, IPropertyBag bizTalkConfig)".
```

On the second Try I get the following Error

```
 The Messaging Engine failed to add a receive location "WcfReceiveLocation_SAPBinding_IdocDEBMAS05V3R740_Custom" with URL "sap://CLIENT=300;LANG=EN;@a/sv-sapecc-dv2/00?GWHOST=sv-sapecc-dv2&GWSERV=sapgw00&ListenerDest=BIZTALKDEV&ListenerGwServ=sapgw00&ListenerGwHost=sv-sapecc-dv2&ListenerProgramId=BIZTALKDEV&RfcSdkTrace=True&AbapDebug=True" to the adapter "WCF-Custom". Reason: "SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcInvalidStateException: destination configuration already initialized
   at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(IDestinationConfiguration config)
   at Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.NCo.RfcServerConnection.Open(RfcClientConnection conn)
   at Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SAPInboundContract.InitializeRfcServerConnectionNCo(String connectionArguments)
   at Microsoft.Adapters.SAP.SAPInboundContract.StartListener(String[] listenerActions, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.Channels.AdapterChannelListener`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfReceiveEndpoint.Enable()
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfReceiveEndpoint..ctor(BizTalkEndpointContext endpointContext, IBTTransportProxy transportProxy, ControlledTermination control)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfReceiver`2.AddReceiveEndpoint(String url, IPropertyBag adapterConfig, IPropertyBag bizTalkConfig)".
```

Any help on how to resolve these errors?

Comment: This problem looks more likely a sap nco sdk issue. I would suggest u to write a simple c# testing code to make sure your url make sense

Comment: Hi,I used the same connection string to consume adapter services in VS2012.It worked over there both with the RFCSdk and NCo connector types.It is just when it comes to Biztalk Recieve location it does,nt work.Also tried with the c# code I was able to Ping sap.

Comment: Also see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3100811

Comment: Can you share your connection string?